# VB.net get element by tag inner text write this in Richtextbox1.text

Tags: vb.net, visual-studio-2019

[image: Please see first here the Idea]

So i wanna make a table in Richbox1 like on Screenshoot

and i get the source i mean the text from a website.

The name (article) and price are in the same div

here the Html Code

```html
<article class="aditem" data-adid="1531911601">
    <div class="aditem-image">
        <div class="imagebox srpimagebox" data-href="/s-anzeige/opel-vivaro-2-0-cdti-84kw-m9r-austauschmotor-einbau-motor/1531911601-280-1651" data-imgsrc="https://i.ebayimg.com/00/s/NDgxWDY0Mw==/z/IIsAAOSwy2Nfe-oK/$_2.JPG" data-imgsrcretina="https://i.ebayimg.com/00/s/NDgxWDY0Mw==/z/IIsAAOSwy2Nfe-oK/$_35.JPG 2x" data-imgtitle="PICTURE" style="cursor: pointer;">
            <img src="PICTURE">
        </div>
    </div>
    <div class="aditem-main">
        <h2 class="text-module-begin">
            <a class="ellipsis" href="Link here example www.example.com/article/example AND I NEED THIS ON NEW LINE ON TABLE LIKE --> NAME | PRICE | LINK TO ARTICLE ">THIS PART I NEED ON FIRST table to Name </a>
        </h2>
        <p>Descripton here &#8203;..</p>
        <p class="text-module-end"></p>
    </div>
    <div class="aditem-details">
        <strong>123 € VB</strong>
        <br>
        PLZ<br>
        Ort/state<br>
    </div>
    <div class="aditem-addon">
        05.12.2020
    </div>
</article>
```

See please the code to understand what i mean

i want the one column for article one for from the article price one from go to the ads link in a text

im not Profi and not Beginner so my codding level is maybe 25 . 30 %

Comment: Please post the VB code as formatted text, not as a picture. At least, not JUST as a picture. Include the picture if it helps but ALWAYS post the code as text.

Comment: What do you want to do with an HtmlElement whose attribute contains 'aditem-details'？

Comment: yes i show the idea on ss

Answer (score 0):

You need to install [HTMLAgilityPack](https://www.nuget.org/packages/HtmlAgilityPack/) nuget package into your project.

Then try the following code.

```
    Dim htmlDoc As HtmlAgilityPack.HtmlDocument = New HtmlAgilityPack.HtmlDocument()
    htmlDoc.Load(New StringReader(WebBrowser1.Document.Body.OuterHtml))
    If htmlDoc.DocumentNode IsNot Nothing Then
        For Each node As HtmlNode In htmlDoc.DocumentNode.SelectNodes("//h2//a")
            Dim hrefValue As String = node.GetAttributeValue("href", "")
            Dim text As String = node.InnerText
            RichTextBox1.Text += text & " | " & hrefValue & vbNewLine
        Next
    End If
```

HtmlAgilityPack uses XPath syntax,check: https://www.w3schools.com/xml/xpath_syntax.asp